# How to get a meaningful error message back to the view controller with Core Data validation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, core-data

**Edit**: I want to let everyone know that in the month since I posted this I've continued to work on the problem. There's now a [repo on github](https://github.com/murraysagal/CoreDataValidationWithiOS) that shows how to easily accomplish this *and* remain compliant with KVC. There's no reason to avoid Core Data validation on iOS. It may be different than on Mac OS X but it's not arduous or difficult.

---

I'm in a view controller editing the properties for a Person object. Person is an NSManagedObject subclass. I'm doing early (before save) validation with Core Data. I'm using the documented `validateValue:forKey:error:` method like this...

```
NSError *error;
BOOL isValid = [person validateValue:&firstNameString forKey:@"firstName" error:&error];
if (!isValid) {
    ...
}
```

And I've got min and max values set in Core Data's model editor in Xcode. When I validate `firstName` and it's too short I get an error like this...

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1670 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1670.)" UserInfo=0x8f44a90 {NSValidationErrorObject=<Event: 0xcb41a60> (entity: Event; id: 0xcb40d70 <x-coredata://ADB90708-BAD9-47D8-B722-E3B368598E94/Event/p1> ; data: {
firstName = B;
}), NSValidationErrorKey=firstName, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1670.), NSValidationErrorValue=B}
```

But there's nothing there that I could display to the user. But the error code is there so I could do something like this...

```
    switch ([error code]) {

        case NSValidationStringTooShortError:
            errorMsg = @"First name must be at least two characters.";
            break;

        case NSValidationStringTooLongError:
            errorMsg = @"First name is too long.";
            break;

    // of course, for real, these would be localized strings, not just hardcoded like this
    }
```

This is good in concept but `firstName`, and other `Person` properties, is editable on other view controllers so that switch would have to be implemented again on whatever view controller edits `firstName`. There must be a better way.

Looking at the Core Data docs for Property-Level Validation reveals this...

```
If you want to implement logic in addition to the constraints 
you provide in the managed object model, you should not override 
validateValue:forKey:error:. Instead you should implement methods 
of the form validate<Key>:error:.
```

So I implemented `validateFirstName:error:` in Person.m. And handily, it executes via the existing `validateValue:forKey:error:` method in the view controller, just as the docs say it will.

But inside `validateFirstName:error:`, `error` is still nil even when `firstName` is too short. When I continue and control returns to the view controller there is an error like at the top of this question but, again, that's too late.  I was hoping that by the time control reached `validateFirstName:error:`, `firstName` would have been validated against the constraints specified in the model editor and the filled in error object would be passed in via the error parameter. But it's not.

I'm left with two ideas that might lead to a good home for the switch statement...

1. In Person.m implement a custom method like `firstNameValidationForValue:error:`. The view controller would call that method. In `firstNameValidationForValue:error:` call `validateValue:forKey:error:`. When it returns with an error, construct a meaningful error message, using the switch, create a new NSError object and return that to the view controller for consumption. This works but it deviates from the standard KVC approach.
2. Remove all the validation from the Core Data model editor in Xcode and perform all of the validation in the methods like `validateFirstName:error:`. Based on the results, construct a meaningful error message, using the switch, create a new NSError object and return that to the view controller for consumption. This has the advantage that the constraints and the error messages are in the same method. And, unlike the first idea, continues to follow the standard KVC approach.

What would you do? Is there another way?

**Edit**: Additional detail on the edit cycle...

The edit cycle begins with the user tapping Add. A new Person object is inserted into the MOC. The view displays a form for editing and Cancel and Done buttons appear on the nav bar. The user starts entering data in fieldA, finishes and taps fieldB. Assume fieldA must be valid before continuing. Before fieldB becomes the first responder the validation for fieldA runs. It fails. The view controller displays the error message returned from the validation and fieldA remains the first responder. The user fixes the problem, and taps on fieldB again. Again the validation runs and this time it passes. fieldB becomes the first responder. This "add data/tap another field or tap Next/validate/move to next field or not" process continues.

It's important to know that at any time the user can tap Cancel. In that case, in terms of the MOC, all I have to do is [myMOC rollback];.

@ImHuntingWabbits: If I invoke `save` instead of `validateValue:forKey:error:` there is a problem with that approach. Assume the user is entering data in fieldA. The user taps fieldB and the validation for fieldA runs. This validation uses the "save and then parse the error" method. But assume it passes and all the other fields also pass. So now the MOC has been saved. But the user has not tapped Done and could very well press Cancel. If the user taps Cancel then the save must be undone. That might be relatively easy if the model was very simple but could be really complex. In my particular case I would not want to take this approach.

**Another Edit**

Can we all reconvene here at github: [github.com/murraysagal/CoreDataValidationWithiOS](https://github.com/murraysagal/CoreDataValidationWithiOS) I've got a sample app there and perhaps a better description of the problem in the readme. The sample app shows that validation, in general, is not at all difficult on iOS. The app demonstrates how it's possible to get a meaningful error message back to the VC *and* remain fully KVC compliant.

And it discusses two possible enhancements to Core Data that I'd like some feedback on before putting them on radar.

Comment: Hey, I have an inkling to inspect the validation error value. See if B is the only thing it says, try longer/shorter/bad char. No docs on it available

Comment: @StephenJ Too long, too short, nil when it shouldn't be, same result. There's a different error code obviously but not a meaningful error I can present to the user.

Answer (score 9):

I would not use Core Data validation for the UI on iOS.  Core Data validation was designed for the desktop with bindings and not for iOS.

You will have a far easier time doing the validation in your view controllers and using Core Data validation as a back up instead of trying to wire Core Data validation to the User Interface.

### Update

> Could you explain why you think it will be easier to implement validation on the View Controller level. While proper validation and error handling is never easy, I can't see a reason why the Core Data level validation should be more complex (besides the issue that validations are possibly performed more than one time, even when it is not required). You also don't answer the case where there is no VC, or when there are more than one VCs handling objects. Also, certain validations can't be performed on VC level (e.g. check for uniqueness of certain properties, which is a pain anyway).

Core Data validation was added for OS X back when there was a fairly tight coupling between Core Data and the user interface.  That coupling was called bindings.  With bindings, entry into a text field was immediately and "automatically" added to the Core Data entity associated with that field.

Further, when that data got updated, Core Data could "respond" with validation back to the text field so that the text field could reject the data entry and explain why it was rejected.

Those bindings do not exist on iOS.  They need to be written, by hand, for every data entry point.

Since we are writing those check points anyway, there is no reason to try and hook into a generic system like Core Data's validation when we can write far more focused validation directly into the view controllers and save ourselves a level of abstraction.

In the case of data importing, we again have a controller handling the import.  There is no direct wiring between the import controller and Core Data anyway so again there in reason to try and plug into a generic system like Core Data's validation when we can write focused code to solve the issue.

Generic systems leak edge cases.  If someone has taken the time to cover most of those edge cases (as in the case of Core Data and bindings on OS X) then go ahead and use them.  But if you must cover those edges or the connective code yourself anyway, there is very little value in integrating into a generic system.  This is especially true of the case where the generic system was not designed to handle the use case (such as Core Data validation and iOS).

There are several parts of Core Data that pre-date iOS and do not fit into iOS very well.  Validation is one of them.

Comment: I just don't think validation belongs in the view controller, it's a model thing. From the Core Data Programming Guide in the Core Data Validation section: "It is important to understand that how to validate is a model decision, when to validate is a user interface or controller-level decision."

Comment: That documentation applies to the desktop when bindings existed and the UI would feed from the validation errors.  Bindings do not exist on iOS and writing your own code would be a horrible hack that is not worth it.  The view controller handles business logic.  Validation can comfortably live in the controller layer.

Comment: I have no Mac OS experience and I don't know what bindings are so I must be missing something. I've implemented with idea 2 above and it doesn't seem at all like a horrible hack. It's working well and I think it's following the KVC conventions. I'm not sure what's not to like.

Comment: With bindings it requires **zero** code to handle validation against Core Data.  The code above gets added to your View Controller right?  You now have validation logic in your controller. If validation logic is going to be in your view controller, might as well put the proper logic in there and get full translation control, along with view specific circumstances and a whole host of flexibility.  The short is: Core Data validation was written for the desktop, it is ill-suited for iOS.

Comment: I discovered the hard way that View Controller validation was the way to go.

Comment: Could you explain _why_ you think it will be easier to implement validation on the View Controller level. While proper validation and error handling is never easy, I can't see a reason why the Core Data level validation should be more complex (besides the issue that validations are possibly performed more than one time, even when it is not required). You also don't answer the case where there is no VC, or when there are more than one VCs handling objects. Also, certain validations can't be performed on VC level (e.g. check for uniqueness of certain properties, which is a pain anyway).

Comment: A view controller should not know anything about validation. If you do so, reusing your model automatically results in duplicated code and that's always a bad, bad thing. Therefore you should add your validation to the model itself or to a higher domain object.

Comment: @FlorianMielke then please explain how you get error messages back to the user on iOS?  Handling of validation is a controller level/business level event. Defining what data should look like belongs in the model, making sure that data is proper is in the controller.

Comment: @FlorianMielke Marcus, I tend to agree with Florian. I implement  the validation in subclasses of managed objects, e.g "User" - as suggested in the documentation. After a user modified an object, the VC just saves the context (or save the "Core Data stack" which saves the whole context chain). `save` returns a detailed error message, that is it contains the managed object, the attribute the kind of validation error. With some effort we can compose a human readable description of the error.

Comment: Why not create a `ValidationManager` class that handles the validation process and contains the mentioned switch. In addition there might be a `ValidationPresenter` class that constructs appropriate `UIAlertView`s. This `ValidationManager` then is independent from the VC. I think with the  introduction of the VC we - including myself - sometimes forget that we are working in an object-oriented language.

Comment: Can we all reconvene here at github: https://github.com/murraysagal/CoreDataValidationWithiOS I've got a sample app there and perhaps a better description of the problem in the readme. The sample app shows that validation, in general, is not at all difficult on iOS. The app demonstrates how it's possible to get a meaningful error message back to the VC and remain fully KVC compliant.

Comment: @MurraySagal Just appended an answer which demonstrates how one can compose a readable error message from a given validation error generated by Core Data. Since we get the error either by explicitly invoking the validation or when we save the context, this solution is orthogonal about the debate whether we should do validation at VC level or let the managed object context generate the error.

Comment: In that github project you are writing exactly what I believe to be a waste of time.  Writing third party frameworks to try and make CD validation work on iOS is a waste of energy to build a generic system that might work in some cases, won't work in all cases, is fragile and virtually unsupported.  Thanks but no thanks, I will stick with writing the validation in the business layer.

Answer (score 3):

Core Data generates validation errors which can be used to automatically compose human readable error messages. It just requires some effort.

The basic structure and the contained information in these errors is consistent, so that we can automate the process.

In order to demonstrate a solution, let's start with a contrived example to understand what Core Data errors are about:

Given:

- A managed object model with an entity "User" with the following attributes, types and constraints defined in the model:

  ```
  User:
      name:        NSString    optional:no
      email:       NSString    optional:no, min_length:3
  ```
- A managed object subclass `User`:

  ```
  @interface User : NSManagedObject

  + (User*) createWithParameters:(NSDictionary*)parameters
          inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context;

  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
  @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSString * user_id;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * email;
  @end
  ```

We can use a `NSDictionary`, representing input values for a managed object subclass "User", and save the managed object context:

For example:

```
NSDictionary* user =   @{
    @"name":        @"John Appleseed",
    @"user_id":     @"634aa621-c63d-4085-aa27-bc3f3b02bcda",
    @"email":       @"e
};
```

**Note:**

> With the values above, we expect to get a validation error for attribute "email", since we have a constraint which requires the string to be at least 3 characters long.

When we try to save and print the error,

```
NSError* error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
}
```

we get something like this (prettified for readability):

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain 
      Code=1670 
      "The operation couldn't be completed. (Cocoa error 1670.)" 
UserInfo=0x2917570 {
    NSValidationErrorObject=<User: 0x28bbc20> (...), 
    NSValidationErrorKey=email, 
    NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1670.), 
    NSValidationErrorValue=e
  }"
```

This error contains the following pieces of information:

- The *error domain* (`error.domain`), which equals always `NSCocoaErrorDomain` for Core Data related errors.
- The *error code* (`error.code`), which equals 1670. This code indicates the actual kind of error (see below).
- A (useless) error description, obtainable via `error.userInfo[NSLocalizedErrorDescriptionKey]`
- The actual managed object (`error.userInfo[NSValidationObjectErrorKey]`)
- The name of the attribute (`error.userInfo[NSValidationKeyErrorKey]`)
- The value of this attribute (`error.userInfo[NSValidationValueErrorKey]`)

As we can see, the error description "The operation couldn't be completed. (Cocoa error 1670.)" is quite useless for a meaningful error description which can be presented to a user. A user would ask, "What actually did go wrong!?"

This important detail is hidden on the *error code*, which is in this case 1670.

We can look up the meaning of this error code in header `<CoreData/CoreDataErrors.h>`:

```
enum {
    NSManagedObjectValidationError                   = 1550,   // generic validation error
    NSValidationMultipleErrorsError                  = 1560,   // generic message for error containing multiple validation errors
    NSValidationMissingMandatoryPropertyError        = 1570,   // non-optional property with a nil value
    NSValidationRelationshipLacksMinimumCountError   = 1580,   // to-many relationship with too few destination objects
    NSValidationRelationshipExceedsMaximumCountError = 1590,   // bounded, to-many relationship with too many destination objects
    NSValidationRelationshipDeniedDeleteError        = 1600,   // some relationship with NSDeleteRuleDeny is non-empty
    NSValidationNumberTooLargeError                  = 1610,   // some numerical value is too large
    NSValidationNumberTooSmallError                  = 1620,   // some numerical value is too small
    NSValidationDateTooLateError                     = 1630,   // some date value is too late
    NSValidationDateTooSoonError                     = 1640,   // some date value is too soon
    NSValidationInvalidDateError                     = 1650,   // some date value fails to match date pattern
    NSValidationStringTooLongError                   = 1660,   // some string value is too long
    NSValidationStringTooShortError                  = 1670,   // some string value is too short
    NSValidationStringPatternMatchingError           = 1680,   // some string value fails to match some pattern
    ...
}
```

So, error code 1670 means "some string value is too short".

In order to exploit this information, we need to setup our own error description table, possibly localized for different languages. I don't want to go into detail how this can be accomplished - it may depend on how you present and compose error messages, but you should get the idea.

For example, we retrieve the following localized error description for error code `1670`:

```
`@"The string for attribute '%@' is too short."`
```

Then, the human readable error description can be composed as follows:

```
NSString* descFormat = [CoreDataValidationErrorHelper errorDescriptionForCode:error.code];
NSString* desc = [NSString stringWithFormat:descFormat, error.user[NSValidationKeyErrorKey]];
```

which should print:

**Error: "The string for attribute 'email' is too short."**

You can tailor this basic approach for your own needs.

Comment: Good explanation of the issue but that solution, I think, is covered in my original question with the code showing the switch statement. Of course, since the original post, the problem has evolved and I can describe it better. The key is getting a good error message back *and* remaining KVC compliant. Please have a look here on github: https://github.com/murraysagal/CoreDataValidationWithiOS

Comment: @MurraySagal I took a look at your project. Let me note a few observations: custom validation run _before_ core data's validation which are defined through constraints in the model. Each validation failure will generate it's own error. The error parameter in the `validate<Key>:error:` method is an _output_ parameter which the method should set as follows: `if (outError) { *outError = myValidationError; }`

Comment: @MurraySagal The purpose of my answer was to show that it is _possible_ to automatically compose an error message. The routine is quite generic. For each scenario you would only need a different set of _error description strings_. Then, you can generate the suitable message from reusable code. Note also, when you implement custom validators, you should basically use the same and consistent userInfo and keys. That is, include all the standardized keys and its associated values as shown above.

Comment: Re: purpose... I grant that I may be missing something but your answer is implemented in the switch statement shown in my original question. Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Re: project... Are you referring to validateLastName:error:?

Comment: @MurraySagal What I'm trying say is, that gathering error info, and _presenting_ the error are two orthogonal concepts. You may have the same object, say "User", but use it in several VCs, or just alone. The one VC may present a different "form" of the error, than the other - nonetheless, the error and the validation procedure, and gathering the pieces of information from the error is alway the same and can be accomplished with reusable code. You only use different "error descriptions" - a table of string formats, tailored for each VC scenario.

Comment: We're in agreement. My additional requirement is that I need to remain 100% KVC compliant. The repo on github shows how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've already considered this, but it seems you could you override NSManagedObject's `- (BOOL)validateForUpdate:(NSError **)error` method in your `Person` class, and call `super`'s implementation to have the MOC validation performed (i.e. have Core Data figure out if your properties fit the restrictions of your data model), and if that returns an error you could do some quick logic to narrow down exactly what the error is and include your own, more verbose, `NSError` object for use by your view controller in the result.

> **Discussion**
>
> NSManagedObject’s implementation *iterates through all of
>   the receiver’s properties validating each in turn*. If this results in
>   more than one error, the userInfo dictionary in the NSError returned
>   in error contains a key NSDetailedErrorsKey; the corresponding value
>   is an array containing the individual validation errors. If you pass
>   NULL as the error, validation will abort after the first failure.
>
> **Important**:  Subclasses should invoke super’s implementation before
>   performing their own validation, and should combine any error returned
>   by super’s implementation with their own (see “Managed Object
>   Validation”).

Based on Apple's documentation I believe this would only get called on a MOC save, but I'm sure you could call it manually to perform your validation ahead of the save as well.

Downsides of this approach are that `validateUpdate:` would get called a minimum of twice for a normal save - once manually and once during the MOC save - so it's a bit inefficient. Also individual pieces of validation logic would be duplicated as well - once by super's implementation and the other by your custom logic figuring out what custom error to return (i.e. you'd be re-checking that `firstName` was indeed what failed validation).

**Edit:** Also, there's nothing in the documentation to suggest this works, but have you tried calling `[super validateFirstName:]` in your subclass' implementation to see if that performs Core Data's validation and gives you the opportunity to return a better NSError? My guess is this won't work but it's worth a shot since it'd be quick to test.

Comment: Regarding the edit, good idea, but calling validateFirstName:error: on super doesn't work. It's not implemented by NSManagedObject.

Comment: You can call validateForUpdate and validateForInsert whenever required. But it's a lot of trouble to unwind the returned NSError to get to the particular error you want. When I weigh that against having the switch duplicated in multiple view controllers I think I'd tip towards the switch.

Comment: If you're interested have a look here at github: github.com/murraysagal/CoreDataValidationWithiOS I've got a sample app there and perhaps a better description of the problem in the readme. The sample app shows that validation, in general, is not at all difficult on iOS. The app demonstrates how it's possible to get a meaningful error message back to the VC and remain fully KVC compliant.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but you'll have to write some fairly sophisticated code to unroll the NSError that comes back from -save:

But it is possible to use that to look up the object in your view controller (or use the one that comes back in the error) and generate a suitable error message. You can also use the key in the error to show UI around the exact field that is causing the issue.

Validation errors have a detailed NSError object that can be used to generate human readable error messages.

```
2014-01-16 10:24:04.983 Untitled[35743:507] Problem: Required
Object ID: 0x7fc173c20170 <x-coredata:///Entity/tA9E1ADE0-CFDF-49D6-AAAA-38CDC935C0982>
Value: (null)
```

Here's the code I used to generate that in CodeRunner:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [[NSEntityDescription alloc] init];
        [entity setName:@"Entity"];

        NSAttributeDescription *attr = [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
        [attr setName:@"Required"];
        [attr setAttributeType:NSStringAttributeType];
        [attr setOptional:NO];
        [entity setProperties:@[attr]];
        [model setEntities:@[entity]];

        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];
        [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:nil];

        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];

        NSManagedObject *obj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
        NSError *e = nil;
        //the process is the same for validating without save, i.e.
        //if ([obj validateForInsert:&e] == NO) ... display error
        [moc save:&e];
            NSLog(@"Problem: %@\nObject ID: %@\nValue: %@", [[e userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSValidationErrorKey"], [[[e userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSValidationErrorObject"] objectID], [[e userInfo] objectForKey:@"Required"]);
    }
}
```

Your switch statement could simply pick apart the error object based on the type of error that occurred, you'll have to make sure you cover the multiple error case as well.

FWIW the difference between doing this pre-save yourself or by calling -save is semantic. You'll be implementing the same iterative code that NSManagedObjectContext uses to validate your object graph.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I need to do this before save.

Comment: Why? Sure you can iterate over the objects and call validateFor... But that seems like a lot of work to duplicate the work that save does.

Comment: I suspected as much. Nested contexts provide a convenient work around, where you can wait until they tap Done to persist the changes to the parent while still saving  incrementally during the editing process. The process of parsing the error though is essentially the same, but you need to switch on update / insert / delete. Not hard just cumbersome without adequate testing.

Comment: If you're interested have a look here at github: github.com/murraysagal/CoreDataValidationWithiOS I've got a sample app there and perhaps a better description of the problem in the readme. The sample app shows that validation, in general, is not at all difficult on iOS. The app demonstrates how it's possible to get a meaningful error message back to the VC and remain fully KVC compliant.

Answer (score 0):

You are halfway there. Getting en error message back would just need some changes.

There is a post [here](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.21/21.09/CoreDataII/index.html) about **Custom Attribute Validation** that explain how to move the validation inside the entity definition. The viewController will then call the validation

### Entity

You overwrite the `validate<Attribute>:error` method and create the error message and the error code. In this example the `error core is` `-1` for `missing`, `to short` and `to long`. And there is only one `message` ("Not valid"). Of corse you can assign separate codes and messages as needed.

For the `FirstName` it would look similar to the following.

```
@interface Person 
extern NSString* const _kErrorDomain

-(BOOL)validateFirstName:(NSString **)value error:(NSError **)error;

@end


@implementation Person
   NSString* const _kErrorDomain = @"ourAppDomain";

-(BOOL)validateFirstName:(NSString **)value error:(NSError **)error {

     if (value == nil || [value length] == 0 || [value length] > toLong) {
        // validation fails
        // create userInfo Dictionary
        NSDictionary *userInfoDict = @{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : 
          @"Not valid"];            // <= text message for User

        // set NSError
        if (error != NULL) 
           *error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:_kErrorDomain // <= our code created the NSError 
                                               code:-1   // <= code for app logic           
                                           userInfo:userInfoDict]; 

        return NO; // fails validation
     }
     return YES; // validated ok
}
```

Unless you would want to get fancy there is little need to override `validateForUpdate:&error` in your entity

---

### ViewController

In my code my viewController calls `validateForUpdate:&error` and will validate the complete `Person`. You might want to call `validateFirstName:error`, the validation should be the same. [*]

```
// ViewController
-(void)checkPerson:(Person *)myPerson  { 
     NSError *error;
     if ([myPerson validateForUpdate:&error]) { 
           // all is well
           error = nil; // zap any previous error
     } else { 
           // validation failed
           if ([[error domain] isEqualToString:_kErrorDomain]) { // error is from our code
              // display error 
              NSLog(@"Error message received: %@", [error localizedDescription ]);

             // handle the errorCode
             if ([error errorCode] == -1)  // do something
             else  // do something else

           } else {
             // error is not our domain. If needed, then take care of the others, too
           }
     } // end if/then validateForUpdate
}
```

The above will keep the validation logic with the entity, while the viewController concentrates on the user.  The validation method can be recycled for multiple viewControllers

---

[*]:
If you do call `validateForUpdate:&error` and more than one attribute is failing validation (NSValidationMultipleErrorsError) then you will receive an array of errors (NSDetailedErrorsKey)

Comment: If you're interested have a look here at github: github.com/murraysagal/CoreDataValidationWithiOS I've got a sample app there and perhaps a better description of my problem in the readme. The sample app shows that validation, in general, is not at all difficult on iOS. The app demonstrates how it's possible to get a meaningful error message back to the VC and remain fully KVC compliant.

Answer (score 0):

[This started as a comment on Marcus's answer, but got too long.]

It would help to understand *how* validation is different on OS X when using bindings, in order to understand why it's different on iOS. With bindings, a typical logic flow would be something like:

- User types data into a text field
- Text field uses its bindings to see if what the user typed is valid
- If the value is valid, no problem. The value can be set on the managed object.
- If the value is *not* valid, alter the UI appearance to indicate this, *and* never set this invalid value on the managed object.

This all happens with no code. A key detail here is that *this never leads to a validation failure when saving changes*, because it's all checked in advance. By the time you call `save:`, you know you at least have valid data.

The **point** of validation, when designed, was to dynamically validate user input against the model to ensure that you never attempted to save invalid data. Invalid data will prevent saving, but that's not really the way validation was meant to be used. Although validation values are stored in the model, using those values is a controller-level step.

When you're on iOS you don't have UI bindings, so if you need to validate values, you need to implement your own code to check every update as it happens. If you don't, and you get invalid input, you won't be able to save changes. You'll get an `NSError` that you have to figure out how to untangle to find out what went wrong. This gets very messy, fast, and is not guaranteed to lead to a useful result.

So, what to do? Check the values on your own, in your view controller. You could use the standard validation methods if you are **extremely** careful to **always** duplicate the process described above. Don't let validation wait until you're saving changes-- do it *immediately* after you get user input. Don't ever set an invalid value on one of your managed objects. If you detect one, advise the user, and don't pass the value through to the model. Basically, make damn sure that you're doing the validation in a controller instead of relying on the model to handle it.

It's safer and less error prone to handle this outside of the standard validation methods. As soon as you implement one of those, you're risking a failed save from validation checks. Implementing your own custom validation methods avoids that, though you still need to be careful to call those methods at the right times.

If it's possible to edit the same value in more than one place, then yeah, either of these options leads to code duplication. That's life-- you don't want to duplicate code, but in practice it's sometimes necessary. Leaving validation until you save is asking for failed saves for confusing reasons.

Comment: It doesn't need to lead to code duplication: you can still pull out the validation code into the model, or a separate model validator class/classes.

Comment: Tom, "this never leads to a validation failure when saving changes", can't be true - since certain validation require more context. For example, if you want to validate a unique attribute. It's not sufficient to check against the current managed object context's registered objects, but instead you have to check the _whole context chain_ down to the persistent store. Doing this manually every time will make your validation code quite elaborate. The alternative is to implement a "saveCoreDataStack" method, which saves the chain and just returns an error - possibly a validation error.

Comment: On the contrary, regardless of bindings, it is really easy to invoke core data validation on iOS way before you call save with either `validateValue:forKey:error' or 'validate<yourProperty>:error:`.

Comment: Can we all reconvene here at github: https://github.com/murraysagal/CoreDataValidationWithiOS I've got a sample app there and perhaps a better description of the problem in the readme.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper The case you are arguing can't be done in Core Data's validation period. There is no uniqueness check in CD validation.  If you want uniqueness to be checked you **MUST** write your own code for it period.

Comment: @MurraySagal I believe I already covered that. Sure you can call it, if you're careful to always do so, but you open yourself up to unexpected save failures.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra I fear you misunderstood me: of course you need to implement these checks yourself. However, it _can_ be done in Core Data's validation methods. While nothing prevents you to create several managed objects with an attribute having the same "unique" value (within the same context) which would violate a "uniqueness constraint" (which does not exist in Core Data), you would not be able to save it, and explicit validation would fail as well.

Comment: And that would happen automatically via Bindings on OS X.  Whereby on iOS it would happen at the save point which is not what you want. So to solve that on iOS you would need to write glue code between the validation methods and the UI to expose those errors **before** saving them. If you are going that far, go one step further and skip CD's validation code and write your own. It will be less code.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra I don't think it matters whether you explicitly validate _before_ save, or just try to save. The effect can be made the same. However, suppose "save" is actually a "deep save", saving a chain of contexts up the to root. Core Data will perform validation for _each_ context. A validation _may_ access the context for further information. IFF a validation needs that info from the context, it would be way to elaborate accomplishing this on the VC level.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Validating at save is a **terrible** user experience. Validation of user input should be done as soon as they leave the field, not at save.  Saving should be done much much later in the UX, possibly when the application is exiting.  Validation and saving are completely separate events.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra No, there is _absolutely no difference_ in User experience. Where is the difference in 1. `if (![user validate:&error]) {...}` and 2. `if (!context save:&error]) { ... }` ? The latter however, ensures concurrency, where the first does not!

Comment: The difference is that you can validate individual attribute values before updating the property, essentially asking "is this specific change OK?" before you make the change. If it isn't, you don't make the change, and you still have valid data. If you wait until saving, you get a single all or nothing success/failure check on data that you've already applied to your managed objects.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Sounds like we have fundamental differences of how an application should work.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the posters here have a misconception about model validation.

If you have a required field that should be longer than 3 letters you should expect to receive two different validation errors for the same field.

Now error for required field would be a nil value, which is a programmer's mistake and if user entered less than 3 letters, this is user input error. My point is that validation error is not meant to be used in user interface directly, instead it should provide a foundation to produce an error that would make sense for user.

So what you want is to implement a helper method that takes a validation error and produces a list of meaningful NSErrors, grouped by field name, ready for presentation in user interface. Based on context you may want to present slightly different messages.

Luckily CoreData returns a lot of information along with validation error, so it's just a matter of extra effort to extract information from userInfo dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the method *setValidationPredicates* in *NSPropertyDescription* (which is the super class for *NSAttributeDescription*). You may specify the validation criteria and the corresponding warnings for various attributes for entities.

From the Apple documentation:

> The *validationPredicates* and *validationWarnings* arrays should contain the same number of elements, and corresponding elements should appear at the same index in each array.
>
> Instead of implementing individual validation methods, you can use this method to provide a list of predicates that are evaluated against
>   the managed objects and a list of corresponding error messages (which
>   can be localized).
>
> **Special Considerations** This method raises an exception if the receiver’s model has been used by an object graph manager.

I am about to implement this, and shall update more on this after testing this approach.